# Срабатывает автозапуск программ при открытии удаленного сенса

Tags: xubuntu

Есть скрип, который нужно выполнять при каждом старте системы. Скрипт запускает определенные программы.
Проблема заключается в том, что при запуске удаленного сеанса снова срабатывает автозапуск этого скрипта и запускаются дубли уже запущенных программ.

Раньше была настроена блокировка повторного запуска при открытии удаленного сеанса, но сейчас не помню как это делается. Помню только что это прописывалось в поле "Команда" (см скрин) через пробел с самим скриптом, но вот что именно там нужно писать не помню.

Подойдет и другое аналогичное решение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может вам поможет Cron?

Comment: Возможно, а как?